# R Loop generating S4 objects

Tags: r, for-loop

i'm new to this forum and I would need some help with the following problem.

I have a loop that is applying a function on several data file. The output of this function is an S4 object with slots.

I would need to save each S4 object generated in each iteration with a different name. I know how to do that by changing the S4 object into a list; in this way, however, I canoot access the slots any more.

Is there a way to do that maintaining the S4object structure?

Here the script

```
Rawlist<-list.files()

outputlist<-list()

for (i in 1:length(Rawlist)){
  Raws <- xcmsRaw(Rawlist[i],profstep= 0.04, includeMSn= TRUE, )
  outputlist[[i]]<-Raws
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't "change the S4 object into a list". You create a list in which you store your S4 objects. Which is, in fact, what you're doing.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're right. My question is : how can access the slot of each S4 object from this list?